# Angular material expansion panel in virtual scroll

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a Virtual scroll feature on my website. Every item in virtual scroll is expansion panel with different count of lines within. When I implement  `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` expansion panels are rendered fine, but when I click on current panel it not expand and only increase his height with maybe 5 px. I don't know how to do it, that expansion panel will expand properly.

I've tried to move expansion panel to `<ng-container>` but id didn't help.

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>
          <span class="panelItem">Id</span>
          <span class="secondPanelItem">Name</span>
          <span class="lastPanelItem">Version</span>
        </mat-card-title>
  </mat-card>
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="viewport">
    <mat-accordion>
      <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let description of allDescriptions">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
              <span class="panelItem">{{description.id}}</span>
              <span class="secondPanelItem">{{description.name}}</span>
              <span class="lastPanelItem">{{description.version}}</span>
            </mat-panel-title> 
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-accordion>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found where was problem. I was setted in scss file height of expansion panel to 50 px so It can't expand more. When I removed this everything is OK.